# Compile nodejs 10.36 for armv7 on armv7

Tags: node.js, gcc, embedded-linux, gnu-make, armv7

I try to compile to compile node.js on an embedded linux in a chroot (armel wheezy) environment. The system has all necessary versions of tools.

- Python 2.7.3
- GCC 4.6
- GNU Make 3.81

CPUInfo:

Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 10 (v7l)
processor   : 0
BogoMIPS    : 790.52

processor   : 1
BogoMIPS    : 790.52

processor   : 2
BogoMIPS    : 790.52

processor   : 3
BogoMIPS    : 790.52

Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x2
CPU part    : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 10

After several tries and research on the web I could compile it, but I receive errors while linking.

I do the following:

```
export CFLAGS='-march=armv7-a'
export CXXFLGAS='-march=armv7-a'
./configure --dest-cpu=armv7 --without-snapshot --without-ssl --dest-os=linux
```

I varied the options, but that had no effect. 
Using as the option --dest-cpu=arm caused an compiling error (no BLX support). Therefore I used armv7, which is the correct CPU on this system.
I receive after compiling and linking the following error:

> /root/node-v0.10.36/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a(platform-posix.o):
>   In function `v8::internal::init_fast_log_function()':
>   platform-posix.cc:(.text+0x598): undefined reference to`
>   v8::internal::CreateTranscendentalFunction(v8::internal::TranscendentalCache::Type)'
>   /root/node-v0.10.36/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a(platform-posix.o):
>   In function `v8::internal::init_fast_sqrt_function()':
>   platform-posix.cc:(.text+0x5e4): undefined reference to`
>   v8::internal::CreateSqrtFunction()' collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status make[1]: *** [/root/node-v0.10.36/out/Release/node] Error 1
>   make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/node-v0.10.36/out' make: *** [node]
>   Error 2

I have no idea, what I can do to link the files. How can I finish the linking process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which worked.

I added the argument -mthumb-interwork and configured it without any parameters. Now it is compiled and installed.

> export CFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork'
>   export CXXFLAGS='-march=armv7-a -mthumb-interwork'